# leaflet pattern . trying to add a path pattern not working

Tags: leaflet, leaflet.draw

based on the documentation here [leaflet.pattern](https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern/blob/master/README.md)

i can create my custom patterns ,[here is an example](https://teastman.github.io/Leaflet.pattern/pattern-path.html)

I have done the same steps  as mentioned in the example for our custom pattern . i have only changed the d element (related to svg path) . 
but things did not went as i expected .

any help would be thankful .

Here is the code :

```
   var mapCenter = new L.LatLng(50.68, -120.34);

    var baseLayer = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
    });

    var _map = new L.Map("map", {
        center: mapCenter,
        zoom: 14,
        layers: [baseLayer]
    });

    var shape = new L.PatternPath({
        d: 'M10 0 L7 20 L25 20 Z',
        fill: true
    });

    var pattern = new L.Pattern({width:50, height:50});
    pattern.addShape(shape);
    pattern.addTo(_map);

    var circle = new L.Circle(mapCenter, 400.0, {
        fillPattern: pattern,
        fillOpacity: 1.0});
    circle.addTo(_map);
```

I have only changed `( d: 'M10 0 L7 20 L25 20 Z')`
to `('m206.38471,149.50017a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828')`

any help would be thankfull

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by making x and y position of your svg path same as the sample's x and y positions.
I've put two paths in same svg file and opened it with an [online editor](https://editor.method.ac/).
As you can see in this screenshot, sample path is located top-left corner, but your path is located in the middle.
[image]
After setting its position same as sample's values: 6px, -1px pattern displayed like this:
[image]

used path: `m8.278722,2.394142a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.05738,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 -3.0574,0a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28827a1.52869,1.64413 0 0 1 0,-3.28828`

If you scale down your path, it is displayed like this:
[image]

used path: `m7.27872,1.318623a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057389,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 -1.057396,0a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137241a0.528694,0.568619 0 0 1 0,-1.137245`